# UILabel numberOfLines

Tags: iphone

I need to adjust `numberOfLines` of label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Label is in word wrap mode.
However, the actual calculation of label's height is taking place in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

How to calculate `numberOfLines` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? For now I'm just using some very big number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Apple Docs:

> To remove any maximum limit, and use
>   as many lines as needed, set the value
>   of this property to 0.

Then you may use this technique in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to determine how tall the cell should be.

Constants:

```
static const CGFloat kCellFontSize = 14.0;
static const CGFloat kCellWidth = 300.0;
static const CGFloat kCellHeightMax = 999.0;
static const CGFloat kCellPadding = 10.0;
```

Method:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake( kCellWidth, kCellHeightMax );

CGSize labelSize = 
        [[self cellTextString] sizeWithFont: [self cellFont] 
                                constrainedToSize: maxSize 
                                    lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

return (labelSize.height + (2 * kCellPadding));
```

Comment: I also use this technique, but the question is `numberOfLines` which I guess better to set during cell construction in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I apologize. I usually set the number of lines to 0, which will cause the label to use as many lines as needed.

Comment: I like to add a min height so my single lines aren't tiny. Couldn't find a constant suited to this purpose, though.